# django 1.10 - custom sql inserts when user registered

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django 1.10 + django-registration 2.2 (HMAC activation workflow).
How can I make custom sql inserts when a new user is registered?
For example every user has own settings and after registration I want to insert the default settings in the sql table for this user. Later the user can change these settings.

What is the common approach? Do I have to edit the django-registration 2.2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use django signals.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


@post_save(sender=User)
def my_callback(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """

    :param sender: 
    :param instance: user instance
    :param created: Inserted or Updated
    :param kwargs: 
    :return: 
    """
    if created is True:
        # Create custom settings for user.
        pass
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save